# Error when running a loop

Tags: r, loops, vector, binary

i am programming in R and i have 184 vectors with 0 or pisitive values. I want to convert them in binary-valued vectors and then make a matrix.

Here's an example of one of these variables

```
     >E1
     [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 26  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  
      0  0  0  0  0  0
     [29]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
      0  0  0  0  0  0
     [57]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
      0  0  0  0  0  0
     [85]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  
      0  0  0  0  0  0
     [113]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
      0  0  0  0  0  0  0
     [141]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
      0  0  0  0  0  0
     [169]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Here's my code:

```
for (i in 1:184){
                 if ( get(paste("E",i,sep="") )>0){

               assign(paste("C",i,sep=""),1)} else{
               assign(paste("C",i,sep=""),0)
                                      }
    }
```

The problem is that the generated C1,C2...C184 are not vectors but only a numeric value. How can i fix that and get a vector? and how can i make a dataframe with the 184 binary-valued vectors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if that's it

```
E1 = round(runif(15, 0, 3))
E2 = round(runif(15, 0, 4))
E183 = round(runif(15, 0, 5))
E184 = round(runif(15, 0, 5))

(data = data.frame(E1, E2, E183, E184))
#   E1 E2 E183 E184
#1   1  3    3    3
#2   0  1    1    3
#3   1  2    3    1
#4   2  1    3    1
#5   2  4    0    0
#6   3  4    4    2
#7   1  3    3    2
#8   1  3    5    5
#9   3  3    1    3
#10  1  1    3    1
#11  2  3    1    0
#12  1  2    3    4
#13  0  1    2    3
#14  3  4    2    2
#15  2  4    2    5

data[data > 0] = 1

colnames(data) = c("C1", "C2", "C183", "C184")

data 
#   C1 C2 C183 C184
#1   1  1    1    1
#2   0  1    1    1
#3   1  1    1    1
#4   1  1    1    1
#5   1  1    0    0
#6   1  1    1    1
#7   1  1    1    1
#8   1  1    1    1
#9   1  1    1    1
#10  1  1    1    1
#11  1  1    1    0
#12  1  1    1    1
#13  0  1    1    1
#14  1  1    1    1
#15  1  1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid using loop and achieve results. Since you have only positives and zeros and you would like to convert all positives to 1, you can use function sign and apply it to database, which could be constructed out of vectors upfront   to function application. Example of code could be as below (in example vectors are combined as rows, though combination as columns is also possible):

```
    V1<- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    V2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    V3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    V4 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2, 0,0,0,0,0,0)
    V5 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    V6 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

    dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6))
    dat <- as.matrix.data.frame(sapply(dat, sign ))
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn´t know about the sign function, that solves half of the problem. Is there any form to create the data frame without typing the name of the 184 variables?